# regular expression to match the text inside a div but ignore the child elements if they exist

Tags: regex, html-parsing

I am trying to match the string that is contained inside a `<div>`
the issue is I need to ignore anything inside of any child elements within the div, I cant seem to get it to match how I need it to.

I have to keep a 3 part format in the regex namely `/^()(.*?)()$/` where

- `()` matches the left side
- `(.*?)` matches the area that I want to
  capture
- `()` matches the right side.

the left and right sides are the starting and stopping points.

lets say I have this HTML:

```
<div class="some stuff">Could Be Anything<span class="specifics">Huge</span></div>
```

now I need to pull out the "Could Be Anything" from the HTML example given without the "Huge" from the child element. following the 3 part rules.

**NOTE:** the `<div` could not have any child elements.. it could just be text (which i want) or text and child elements

my attempt was `/^(>)(.*?)(<span)$/` but that didn't work, and I don't know where to go from here. any help would be appreciated!

#### EDIT:

for a more clear picture of what I am trying to do.

I am trying to return some sports stats from a webpage. i'm using kimonolabs to scrape a webpage. the element i'm trying to scrape is a  inside a table. this  contains a  that has some text inside it. kimono uses css selectors to know which element to pull from. and then regex is an option to filter anything else. so right now if the div has another element inside it it returns that elements text aka the 's text but I don't want that

Comment: Don't do this. Don't use regex to parse HTML. Or to extract possibly complicated data, like this.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I have to. It is the only option that I have. if you want to know why I can try and explain (theres a bit that goes into it) also the data is always going to be a simple string

Comment: What regex flavor/language and did you mean that also div can be nested inside div?

Comment: `/^(.*>)(.*?)(<span)$/`?

Comment: @Jonny5 it would be just generic raw regex... and no its only a span inside the div. sometimes there isn't a span depending on if there is a specific given or not

Comment: @skobaljic I wish I could use php or jquery for this, unfortunately I cant.

Comment: So what do you use man? Cant be this is just a theoretical question?

Comment: @skobaljic I am using a web crawler to retain some sports info... it uses css selectors to get to an element.. there is an advanced option to use regex to filter what is retained from there... so thats what I have to work with

Comment: Why dont you use simple `/>(.*?)</` - it is not greedy, will catch first string in between the tags.

Comment: @skobaljic if you read in my question i have to follow their three part regex or its considered invalid [see docs](https://help.kimonolabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/203043464-Manually-input-regular-expressions) - also that would match the string inside the <span> and i want to exclude that

Comment: @Clive thanks for the attempt but that is also something I tried :(

Comment: Would something [like this](https://regex101.com/r/qS5eB6/1) and grab the 2nd capture group work for you? Still not sure if I understand it right :)

Comment: @skobaljic again that would match the string inside the span and I don't want that. I just want the first part.

Comment: @Jonny5 you have the right idea... few things 1 there will only be this format `<div>text</div>` OR `<div>text<span>text1</span></div>` so for both cases I need just the 'text' part but not the 'text1'... 2 the regex you provided doesn't work with the service I have because it has to be in the format (match beginning)(my actual contents)(match ending)... the three parenthesis are supposed to match the beginning of where I want to start, then the actual characters aka (.*?) and then the ending point of the match does that make sense?

Comment: What about `(<div[^>]*>)([^<]+)(<)` [test here](https://regex101.com/r/qS5eB6/2)?

Comment: @Jonny5 That will fail for html like `<div class=">" get-data="" seg=">" test>eyhrtfu<span>`. This is actually valid code.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel except that is not what the data is?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel OP only wants some simple regex that complies with the *3 part rule* and get the stuff matched from his data :p possibly there's no such awful in it.

Comment: @Jonny5 For this arbitrary small set, there isn't any harm. In that I agree. But HTML isn't a *regular* language and you may expect any type of bad ill code.

Comment: @JohnRuddell Something like `(^.*?">)([^<>]+)(<)` [won't work](https://regex101.com/r/rA3mR7/1)? @IsmaelMiguel Of course it depends on the feeded data.

Comment: @Jonny5 it isn't right now.. but I don't know why since that matches what I specified. testing it to see what the issue is :)

Comment: Can you edit the question please? Add the requirements and the reason why you have them, as you explained in my answer, on the comments.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I don't see the need to since the requirements are the requirements. I figured out a solution, it was a combination of yours and johnny5s answers i'll accept it shortly +1 all around

Comment: @Jonny5 if you want to post your example as an answer i'll upvote :)

Comment: Thanks @JohnRuddell I just was interested :) Glad you got it going! What was the  actual culprit? Requires `^` and `$`, no delimiters... ?

Comment: It's just to remove the downvote. And if you post your answer, I'll upvote it.

Comment: @Jonny5 and IsmaelMiguel the issue was I needed to include the start of string and end `/^(>)([^<]*)(<span|)$/` I needed to also include the pipe for when there isn't a span

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

The solution for the specific O.P.'s problem is the following regex:

```
/(^)([^<]*)(<span)/i
```

The last flag can be ignored for this problem.

This assumes that it is matching against the content inside the `<div>` tag.

---

In case the HTML code is overly complicated/ill, this is the regex I came up with:

```
/<div(?:\s*[a-z_\-]+(?:=(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^>]+))?)*>([^<]+)<span/i
```

This is OVERLY complicated.

This works with most badly formatted code.

It works as required: saves the data inside a `<div>` but before a `<span>`.

You can test it and check it in action here: https://regex101.com/r/tT1xM4/1

---

**Disclaimer**

Altough I made this regex, regexes aren't the right tool for this!

DO NOT USE REGEX FOR THIS KIND OF COMPLICATED DATA!

I give no warranty that this will work with EVERY AND ANY POSSIBLE ARBITARY HTML code.
I took care to support ugly code like `<div class=">" get-data="" seg=">" test>eyhrtfu<span>` (which correctly matches `eyhrtfu`) but this isn't a perfect solution.

If you want a perfect solution, use jQuery/document.querySelectorAll/Prototype or phpQuery or other parsing technique.

Comment: thanks for the answer but your regex didn't follow the three rules i put in the question so it returns an invalid regex error :(

Comment: @JohnRuddell Where are you trying it? How can I test my regex against such system?

Comment: let me give you a clear picture so it will make more sense :) I am trying to return some sports stats from a webpage. i'm using kimonolabs to scrape a webpage. the element i'm trying to scrape is a <td> inside a table. this <td> contains a <div> that has some text inside it. kimono uses css selectors to know which element to pull from. and then regex is an option to filter anything else. so right now if the div has another element inside it it returns that elements text aka the <span>'s text but I don't want that

Comment: some helpful links... https://help.kimonolabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/203069324-Manipulate-kimono-s-data-selections-with-advanced-mode ..... https://help.kimonolabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/203043464-Tailor-the-regex-for-your-data-types

Comment: @JohnRuddell Alright, I've made an edit and shower my solution for you. Anything you might need, just ask here. If you want me to explain, just ask.

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of strings:

```
 <div class="some stuff">Could Be Anything<span class="specifics">Huge</span></div>
```

Following regex will strip first text in between the tags:

```
    /(>)(.*?)(<)/

1st Capturing group (>)
    > matches the characters > literally
2nd Capturing group (.*?)
    .*? matches any character (except newline)
        Quantifier: *? Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]
3rd Capturing group (<)
    < matches the characters < literally
```

Total one match for the above example:

```
1.  [23-24] `>`
2.  [24-41] `Could Be Anything`
3.  [41-42] `<`
```

Please note, there should be no modifiers, specially no global **g** modifier.

Here is the screenshot of matches, source https://www.regex101.com/:
[image]

Comment: go to http://regexpal.com/ paste in the html and the regex you provided you will see this matches more than once (remember to remove the / from both sides as its already included by the website)

Comment: Than it must have global modifier at the end. You have never mentioned it. Without any modifier it works fine. Paste the code at https://www.regex101.com/ and see yourself. `/(>)(.*?)(<)/g` would match span too.

Comment: sigh... I don't want to match the span. i only want to match the "Could Be Anything"... it matches 3 times

Comment: I really do know where you see those 3 matches. I asked **Kimono's support** (which is great) and they answered with following: `You should be able to use regex to get the text inside of div and not span. Our regex is a bit different because it uses a left and right border. Is the text inside the span going to be fairly consistent? If so, this should be possible.` So, if they say it is fine, why wouldn't you also agree?

Comment: I already have a working solution to the issue now. the text inside is fairly consistent though